# I am having some troubles with the flutter align widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, alignment

I try to align the child with bottomCenter. The child widget is positioned in the middle but not in the bottom of the screen.

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Text('Player 1:'),
  ),
),
```

This align widget is in a column so it might be some column height error. And when I add expanded I get a error:

> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#64524 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

All of the code is here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const HomeScreen(),
  );
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Dice'),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Dice(),
              ],
            )));
  }
}

class Dice extends StatefulWidget {
  const Dice({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Dice> createState() => _DiceState();
}

class _DiceState extends State<Dice> {
  List dices = [
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
  ];

  List showingdices = [
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    5,
  ];

  var pointcount = 0;

  int setnum = 0;
  rolldices() {
    for (int i = 0; i < dices.length; i++) {
      if (dices[i] != 0) {
        setState(() {
          setnum = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
          dices[i] = setnum;
          showingdices[i] = setnum;
        });
      }
    }

    points();
  }

  int pointer = 0;

  points() {
    int stopper = 0;
    var map = {};

    for (var element in dices) {
      if (!map.containsKey(element)) {
        map[element] = 1;
      } else {
        map[element] += 1;
        if (map[element] == 3) {
          if (element == 1) {
            pointer = element * 1000;
          } else {
            pointer = element * 100;
          }

          for (var thing in dices) {
            if (thing == element && stopper < 3) {
              stopper += 1;
              dices[dices.indexOf(element)] = 0;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    for (var element in dices) {
      if (element == 1) {
        pointer += 100;
        setState(() {
          dices[dices.indexOf(element)] = 0;
        });
      }
      if (element == 5) {
        pointer += 50;
        setState(() {
          dices[dices.indexOf(element)] = 0;
        });
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      pointcount += pointer;
    });
  }

  Reset() {
    setState(() {
      dices = [
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
        5,
      ];
      pointcount = 0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          pointcount.toString(),
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Image.asset(
                        'images/' + showingdices[0].toString() + '.png'))),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Image.asset(
                        'images/' + showingdices[1].toString() + '.png'))),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Image.asset(
                        'images/' + showingdices[2].toString() + '.png'))),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Image.asset(
                        'images/' + showingdices[3].toString() + '.png'))),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Image.asset(
                        'images/' + showingdices[4].toString() + '.png')))
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: rolldices, child: const Text('Roll The Dice!')),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: Reset, child: const Text('Reset')),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Text('Player 1:'), //Your widget here,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: We need more context to understand the real problem. Anyway, if you want it to be fixed to the bottom of the screen, you can add it to bottomNavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Column widget the default of its main axis alignment is center. If you wish to place it at the bottom center try adding Spacer inside the Column which will occupy all the available space. Make sure you have bounds for the column like

```
Sizedbox(
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
 width : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Column(
    children: [
     //Other widgets here
       Spacer(),
       Row(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         children: [
          Text('player1'),
         ]
        )
      )
    ]
   )
)
```

Comment: When i add expanded i get a error. Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#1732e relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT      
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Comment: Edited my answer. The expanded alsi would need a bound. The edited approach is better.. please try that